# Where can I find good study material on Role Mining?

Tags: education, reference-request, security, access-control

I need to cover these topics in Role Mining. If anyone knows good site which well summarizes the topics and concepts are well explained please help out.

Basic role mining problem
• Delta-approx RMP
• Min-noise RMP
• Nature of the RMP problems
• Mapping RMP to database tiling problem
• Minimum tiling problem
• Mapping min-noise RMP to database tiling problem
• Mapping RMP to minimum biclique cover problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper [The Role Mining Problem: Finding a Minimal Descriptive
Set of Roles](http://cimic.rutgers.edu/~jsvaidya/pub-papers/vaidya-sacmat07rm.pdf) by Jaideep Vaidya, Vijayalakshmi Atluri and Qi Guo covers the basic definitions and some variants and includes a mapping to the minimum tiling problem. This is explored in more detail in the third author's PhD thesis (found by Googling "A formal approach to the role mining problem.)

An alternative formal definition of the Role Mining problem is found in the paper [On the Deﬁnition of Role Mining](http://www.mariofrank.net/paper/DefOfRoleMining_SACMAT2010.pdf) by 
Mario Frank, Joachim M. Buhmann, and David Basin. This is another good starting point;  it also contains references to much of the earlier work.

These [tutorial slides](http://www.mariofrank.net/paper/CCS%20Tutorial%20on%20Role%20Mining.pdf) cover many of the topics you mention. They also contain a load of references for you to follow up. The author of these slides has a small [page](http://www.mariofrank.net/rolemining.html) describing the basics of role mining.

[Optimal Boolean Matrix Decomposition: Application to Role Engineering](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICDE.2008.4497438) by Haibing Lu, Jaideep Vaidya and Vijayalakshmi Atluri covers basic RMP along with min-noise RMP, $\delta$-approximate RMP and edge-RMP using boolean matrix decomposition as the basic formalism.